# SAS Call Symput - INTNX returning inconsistent dates

Tags: date, macros, sas

I'm trying to use the call symput below to grab the most recent Friday and Sunday from the previous week. For example, if I run it today (5/17/2016) then it should grab 5/13/2016 and 5/15/2016. However, I'm getting strange results. The first time I run this piece of code, it results in no dates, or it results in 5/6/2016 and 5/8/2016. If I immediately run the same piece of code again then it provides the correct dates. This happens every time I open a new SAS session. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated...

```
data _null_;

%global beg end;

call symput ('beg',"'"||put(intnx('week.6',date(),-0,'b'),mmddyy10.)||"'");
call symput ('end',"'"||put(intnx('week.1',date(),-0,'b'),mmddyy10.)||"'");

put &beg;
put &end;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert's comment below does a good job explaining what is going on here:

> It's more to do with understanding how the macro pre-processor works. Basic rule of thumb is don't try and access macro variables in the same datastep they were created when using symput. If you absolutely have to you can get around this by using symget

A similar example is discussed towards the middle of [this page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/62978/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1rvuiao0okk6cn1afs9ckt2unh9.htm); control+f "Resolving Macro Resolution Problems Occurring During DATA Step Compilation"). And the following code should fix your issue!

```
%global beg end;

data _null_;
    call symput ('beg',"'"||put(intnx('week.6',date(),-0,'b'),mmddyy10.)||"'");
    call symput ('end',"'"||put(intnx('week.1',date(),-0,'b'),mmddyy10.)||"'");
run;

data _null_;
    put &beg.;
    put &end.;
run;
```

Comment: Yep...looks like that fixes it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should provide a synopsis of the information contained in the link (in case it breaks).  Also, it has nothing to do with 'compilation', it's more to do with understanding how the macro pre-processor works.  Basic rule of thumb is don't try and access macro variables in the same datastep they were created when using `symput`.  If you absolutely have to you can get around this by using `symget`.

Comment: @RobertPenridge Sounds like you should post that as an answer - it's the right one, IMO.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that's very helpful info! I'll keep that in mind for any future use of macros.

Comment: @superfluous - feel free to copy/paste/paraphrase my comments in your answer rather than just referring to it

Comment: @Robert Penridge - Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should use %PUT after the RUN to see the values of the macro variables BEG and END.  No need for extra data step.

```
%put NOTE: &=BEG &=END;
```

Comment: Why?  This answer is doesn't really help the OP understand what is going wrong at all.